# Matching string between two markers that are filepaths and contain special characters

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to write a ruby script that will return text between two other strings. The issues is that the two matching string contain special characters. Escaping the special characters is not solving the problem.

I've tried escaping special characters, different matching patterns, and providing variables with the matching strings without much luck.

I've also tested a simplified match by using only **ODS** and **NAME** as delimiters. That seemed to work.

```
####Example contents of logfile 
#### 'aaaaaaaaa ODS | Filename = /tmp/bbbbbb | NAME = ccccc'

log_to_scan = 'logfile'
marker1 = 'ODS | FILENAME = /tmp/'
marker2 = ' | NAME'

contents = File.read(log_to_scan)

print contents.match(/ODS \| FILENAME = \/tmp\/(.*) \| NAME/m[1].strip

print contents.match(/marker1(.*)marker2/m)[1].strip
```

Given the sample contents above, I am expecting the output to be bbbbbb. However, I am getting either nothing or a NoMethod error. Not sure what else to true or what I'm mistake I'm making.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = 'aaaaaaaaa ODS | Filename = /tmp/bbbbbb | NAME = ccccc'
marker1 = 'ODS | FILENAME = /tmp/'
marker2 = ' | NAME'
```

```
r = /(?<=#{Regexp.escape(marker1)}).*(?=#{Regexp.escape(marker2)})/i
  #=> /(?<=ODS\ \|\ FILENAME\ =\ \/tmp\/).*(?=\ \|\ NAME)/i 
str[r]
  #=> "bbbbbb"
```

or

```
r = /#{Regexp.escape(marker1)}(.*)#{Regexp.escape(marker2)}/i
str[r,1]
  #=> "bbbbbb"
```

or, if the string to be matched is known to be lower-case, or it is permissible to return that string downcased:

```
s = str.downcase
  #=> "aaaaaaaaa ods | filename = /tmp/bbbbbb | name = ccccc" 
m1 = marker1.downcase
  #=> "ods | filename = /tmp/" 
m2 = marker2.downcase
  #=> " | name" 
id1 = s.index(m1) + m1.size
  #=> 32
id2 = s.index(m2, id1+1) - 1
  #=> 37
str[id1..id2]
  #=> "bbbbbb"
```

See [Regexp::escape](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-escape). In #1,

```
(?<=#{Regexp.escape(marker1)})
```

is a *positive lookbehind*, requiring `marker1` to appear immediately before the match.

```
(?=#{Regexp.escape(marker2)})
```

is a *positive lookahead*, requiring `marker2` to immediately follow the match.

In #3, I used the form of [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-index) that takes a second argument ("offset").

Comment: Thanks for the help! This worked great and is similar to the original grep command I had written. Since I'm parsing an entire log file, I added string scan and match as indicated by Emma's response.

Answer (score 2):

Your original expression is just fine, we would be slightly modifying it here, if there might be other additional spaces in your string input and it might work:

```
^.+?ODS(\s+)?\|(\s+)?FILENAME(\s+)?=(\s+)?\/tmp\/(.+?)(\s+)?\|(\s+)?NAME(\s+)?=(\s+)?(.+?)$
```

and our desired outputs are in these two capturing groups:

```
(.+?)
```

#### Test

```
re = /^.+?ODS(\s+)?\|(\s+)?FILENAME(\s+)?=(\s+)?\/tmp\/(.+?)(\s+)?\|(\s+)?NAME(\s+)?=(\s+)?(.+?)$/mi
str = 'aaaaaaaaa ODS | Filename = /tmp/bbbbbb | NAME = ccccc'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYzzOx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

How about `String#scanf`?

```
> require 'scanf'
> str = 'ODS | FILENAME = /tmp/ | NAME'
> str.scanf('ODS | FILENAME = %s | NAME')
=> ["/tmp/"]
```